# Image in products list-magento

Tags: php, magento

I created a new custom category attribute image to show up as a banner image. Everything works fine. Now i want to put that in product list but just under the first row of products.My row have only 3 products and if  i add more products, another row is created by default. I want to set up that banner image between first and second row and only there, not after every row of products that is created by default.I'm new in magento and i would be grateful if you could help me to do that. I heard something about $i++ but i don't know exactly how to manage that. Thank you!

Comment: $productCount % 3 == 0 ? (i.e. look up the Modulus operator)

Comment: This will set up my banner image under each one product. I want it under first row of products. Thank you aniway :)

Comment: No it won't it'll put it in after exactly 3 products (or multiples thereof) ... so yeah, $productCount == 3 would make more sense

Comment: I finally manage to do that by adding an if statement in list.phtml/grid system who looks like that <?php if($i++ == 3):?><baner image code><?php endif;?>. I put that after <?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product): ?>. :)